# What is the difference between **pointer and &pointer as function parameter?

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

```
#include <stdio.h>

void initialize(int **);
void control(int **);

int main(void){

    int *pointer;
    printf("%p\n",pointer);
    initialize(&pointer);
    printf("%p\n",pointer);
    control(&pointer);

    return 0;
}

void initialize(int **point){
    printf("%p\n",point);
    *point = NULL;
    printf("%p\n",point);
}
void control(int **point){
    if(*point == NULL)
        printf("hi");
    else
        printf("good bye");
}
```

There is no problem in the code above, but when I change it like this:

```
int **pointer;
printf("%p\n",pointer);
initialize(pointer);
printf("%p\n",pointer);
control(pointer);
```

It doesn't work properly. I wonder why it doesn't work same as **&pointer**.

Comment: `&pointer` cannot be a function parameter

Comment: I read C Primer Plus and author used it in Linked List section(Chapter 17).I don't get any problem when I use it @M.M

Comment: maybe you are not using a C compiler then

Comment: What do you mean? I use GCC with Dev-C++ and I don't get any error. @M.M

Comment: perhaps post the code you are talking about (nothing in the question has `&pointer` as a parameter)

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code and it gives Segmentation fault, which should be caused by null pointer, when the pointer of null pointer is assign to null in the initialize() function.